# Auto delete spam email from a domain in Gmail

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I want to auto delete email from the spam folder if they are from a particular domain, is it possible?

For example, if an email message is marked as SPAM and it is from `example.com`, don't keep it in the SPAM folder

I want to keep my SPAM folder clean so it will be more easy to check if I missed some important mails.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Settings, select "Filters". Scroll to the bottom and select "New filter". Put `@domain.com`  in the `from` field. If you want it to only check email that have gone to spam, put `in:spam` in the `has the words` field. Now click "Create filter with this search":

[image]

Now, an new window will appear. Tick "Delete it", then click "Create filter", and you ought to be ready to go!

[image]

Comment: The problem with this approach is the whole domains is blocked. I only want to delete email from this domain if it is only marked as SPAM.

Comment: @Yoga: Fixed :)

Answer (score -2):

You can setup filters to delete it.

Go to setting and then filter.