# Discarding spam mail faster in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Sometimes I like to browse my spam folder, to make sure I'm not passing by something that is important. The problem is that there is so much spam that is even hard browse through it.

I notice some very distinguishable patterns, and I was wondering if there is some way that the emails that meet those patterns could be 100% deleted automatically, to help me browse through the folder with more ease.

For instance:

"Delete all mails that are detected as spam and contain the word 'viagra'"

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as a one-step process.

It's simple enough to perform a keyword search in your spam label. Just do something like

```
in:spam viagra
```

Once you've got your results just check all and delete.

Comment: I was hoping to build some filter or step that would make it automatically

Comment: Not really, no. "In:spam" will never match incoming mail. Related question: [Auto delete spam email from a domain in Gmail](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/35572)

Comment: That thread had the answer. Thank you!